# Задача Четные числа не могу решить помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x

У нас есть числа от L до R. R вводит человек и нужно найти количество четных чисел.
я пытался сделать сам.

```
L=1
R=int(input())
d=0
range(L,R)
while L < R:
    if L%2==0:
        d+1
        L+1
    else:
        L+1
print(d)
```

но почему то когда я запускаю программу и ввожу число дальше программа не раблтает. Помогите

Comment: Потому что вы забываете поместить результаты вычислений в переменные d и L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать циклы для этой задачи нерационально. Прежде, чем садиться программировать решение задачи, нужно подумать над тем, как именно она решается. Вот пример решения без циклов:

#### Upd: правая граница теперь не учитывается по заявлению автора вопроса

```py
L=1
R=int(input('Введите R'))
d=(R-L)//2
print(d)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. Но когда запускается программа он считает 10 за число. Можно сделать так чтобы он не считал 10 а остановился на 9

Comment: @user363495, обновил ответ